# Is there any free cross platform setup builder tool available?

Tags: cross-platform, installation, setuptools

There are commercial cross-platform install tools out there and i think that they are really useful because you "compose" your setup once and the setup tool compiles it for the target platforms you want it to work for.

Unfortunately, such tools are expensive for a shareware author like me -  they cost thousands of dollars. Are there similar open source projects out there?

Thanks in advance,

David

Comment: It's really hard to tell if this is an ad or not.  You might want to clarify exactly what it is you want a "cross-platform setup tool" to do.

Comment: I'm sorry, i didn't intend to make it look like an ad. I've edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IZPack does very fine, i think. It's comprehensive, cross-platform and has a commercial-friendly license.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same problem. Looked into IZPack, IZPack with Native Laucher, Lauch4J, ... All of them way too complex to use, at least for my taste. Searching for more info on IZPack, I've run accross that one a minute ago almost by accident: http://www.installjammer.com/

Looks promising, haven't tried it yet, though.